# Finding the order in which integer grid-points are encountered by an expanding circle centered at the origin

Tags: geometry, number-theory

> There is a dot at each integer $x$ and $y$ value of a two-dimensional grid, each vertex of typical graph paper. You place a circle of radius zero at the origin $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. You slowly expand the circle by increasing the radius. In what order will the circle encounter the dots?

Because of symmetry I am only considering points with $y>=0$ and $x>=y$. The first few points encountered are ordered as
$$(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (4,0), (4,1), (3,3), (4,2), \text{tie: } (4,3) \text{ and } (5,0)$$

I am interested if there is a formula or rule for the next dot. I was thinking the solution would look like $axn(x,y,n)$ and $ayn(x,y,n)$, recursive formulas that return the next $x$ and $y$ value respectively. But that might be impossible because of the tie. Maybe the question doesn't have a solution and you just have to keep guessing and checking, but that would be unsatisfying.

I have created a list of the first few distances squared as well.
$0,1,2,4,5,8,9,10,13,16,17,18,20,25,25,26,29,32,34,36,37,40,41,45,49,50,50,52,53,58,61,64,65$

I also created an app to draw a graph connecting the vertices in the order that they appear. There are splits for vertices encountered concurrently. The graph is very chaotic and there are self-intersections for larger radii. This graph makes me think the problem is more difficult than I initially realized.

[this is a zoomed-in view of the first 17 vertices encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERKto.png)

[this is a zoomed-out view of the first 871 vertices encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWYuD.jpg)

Also to add to the complexity, even more, There are 3 and 4-way ties. The first of each respectively is $325 = 15^2 + 10^2 = 17^2 + 6^2 = 18^2 + 1^2$ and $1105 = 24^2 + 23^2 = 31^2 + 12^2 = 32^2 + 9^2 = 33^2 + 4^2$.

Comment: Sort all grid points by their distance to $(0,0)$. Same distance means that the circle touches them at the same time. If the circle can increase its radius only by integer steps then it will overpass many points, thouse with $\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$ not being an integer.

Comment: Sorting all grid points by their distance to (0,0) is only restating the problem. I want to know why they are sorted in that order. Also, the radius increases continuously, non-integer increases.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY

The YouTube channel 3blue1brown has a very interesting video regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but perhaps helpful.

The squares of the radii are just the integers that can be represented as the sum of two squares. Lots is known about these numbers. In particular, you can predict where the ties will occur. I doubt that there is a nice way to calculate the $n$th one, or the next one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: Yea I found this article almost the same time as you. It's probably the closest I'm gonna get to a solution. And it makes me think the problem is a lot harder than it initially appears.